# Push notification does not work on mobilefirst platform 7.1 server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have develop a cross platform app with mobilefirst studio 7.0 and test it on production environment.
It was fine before we upgrade our project with mobilefirst studio 7.1.0.00-201510120-1525 and test it on clean staging server (7.1.0.0 20151012-1525).
It seems that the push notification functionality dedicated on mobilefirst 7.0 did not work properly on production server of mobilefirst platform version 7.1.  The source code and configuration file of our mobilefirst push notifcation adapter and configuration files are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bKYLGMis9MbVVqYmctSlBoLVk).

Inorder to fix the issue, we refer to official push notification tutorial which was documented [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/event-source-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/).
Surprisingly, although [the source project in official tutorial](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/EventSourceNotifications?cm_mc_uid=32044470596514461899990&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1446189999) looks fine on development server, it still not work on production server either.
We have test this project using iphone5s with ios 8.4 and HTC 816h phone with android 4.4.2, both of them fail to register push notification service after we login to the HybridEventSource sample application and tap the “Subscribe Notification” button.
The Mobilefirst server logs down internal server error message during the registration process of client devices.

I am wondering how to let the push notification mechanism work again on mobilefirst 7.1?
Either a valid push notification sample code of mobilefirst 7.1 or any fix pack which we do not know is welcomed.
Since we did not authenticate users via mobilefirst server, and devices were connected through vpn to server, 
we prefer to have a solution which does not depends on particular mobilefirst server side authentication mechanism.

The server log message generated during this test is [in this file.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bKYLGMis9MUmtyTTZlMXQ3RjQ)
The log file generated while we run EventSourceNotification app as xcode project is [in this file.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bKYLGMis9Ma1lsNEN2SFdUc28)
For detail system log from ios device, please refer to [device log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bKYLGMis9MZ245cjRaUTFiQTg)
And the Log message generated by HTC 816h android 4.4.2 phone is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bKYLGMis9MbTI1d2h1S2tESFk)

Information about our server environment:
Operating system : centos 5.8 linux
Java development kit : Oracle jdk 1.8 update 65 x86-64
Application server : Apache tomcat server 7.0.63
Worklight environment database : oracle database 11g.
Apple push notification service certificate : sandbox version

Comment: I suspect your production server setup prevents it from working. Can you please double-check that you have all addresses and ports open to incoming/outgoing connections as per the getting started documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's kinda suspicious, isn't it?

> Since we did not authenticate users via mobilefirst server, and devices were connected through vpn to server, we prefer to have a solution which does not depends on particular mobilefirst server side authentication mechanism.

You are using the push mechanism provided by MFPF but you do not want to go through MFPF? You are required to go through MFPF if you want to use the push mechanism provided by MFPF... What did you mean by the above?

That said, did your DBA examine mf7-1-EventSourceNotifications-catalina.out.log? There are quite a few Oracle-related exceptions there that you should look at.

If you are still unable to resolve it I suggest to open a PMR instead so that the development team will be able to further investigate.